# docker-desktop wsl time sync

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux, docker-desktop

I have an issue with the docker-desktop wsl "system?".

I have not installed docker-desktop with hyper-v support.

When I do a `wsl -i -v` on a cmd I get:

```
C:\windows\system32>wsl -l -v
  NAME                   STATE           VERSION
* docker-desktop         Running         2
  docker-desktop-data    Running         2
```

And I do not want an extra OS like e.g. Ubuntu.

I cannot do any sudo or apt install. When I try to do a wsl sudo, wsl say "/bin/sh: sudo: not found" and so on.

I would like to run the "sudo ntpdate" command but since it cannot find sudo I am out of luck.

If I try to do "wsl ntpdate..." it says the same "/bin/sh: ntpdate: not found".

What are my options ?

Comment: As wsl uses windows time, can you just sync windows time?

Answer (score 3):

the command `hwclock -s` worked for me! If on Windows, you can just run this command in powershell and Docker will have the correct time again:

`wsl -d docker-desktop -e "hwclock -s"`

Because this issue mostly occurs (in my experience) when using the sleep mode in Windows, you might want to create a Scheduled Task in Windows. You can create a basic task, Use the specific event trigger mode, And use these settings as source:

- Logbook: `System`
- Source: `Kernel-Power`
- Event ID: `507` (The system is exiting connected standby)

You can then run this:

- Program: `c:\Windows\System32\wsl.exe`
- Parameters: `-d docker-desktop -e "hwclock -s"`

You will see a window of the wsl.exe after every wake, but this will automate the temporary fix.

Comment: after 6 hours of searching timestamp error has gone